# How can I run spark-submit in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I have tried to run a spark-submit job in a jupyter notebook to pull data from a network database:

```
!spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.10:2.0.0 script.py
```

and got this message:

> jupyter: '/home/user/script.py' is not a Jupyter command

Is there an option to submit from the notebook.

KR

Comment: You didn't include the crucial information - looks like you set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` (or some equivalent) to `jupyter`. `jupyter` can run scripts directly only via `run`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its an `ipykernel`, i do not see a requirement to do a spark submit, you are already in interactive spark mode where `sparkContext` and `sqlContext` is already created and available for the whole session you kernel is up. 
Seems like you are trying to create a cascade sort-of operation i.e. have spark application inside spark application and so on. You cannot have that with Spark.

you can start a normal python kernel and then run `spark-submit` as a shell command using `Popen` or other such libraries and functions.

Comment: with this I'd say, that the issue is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell magic:

```
%%sh
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.10:2.0.0 script.py
```

See more magics [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)!

Comment: Thanks @Tim, seems like a step forward. 
However with running the magic I still get the same issue:

'jupyter: '/home/user/script.py' is not a Jupyter command'

Comment: Are you using the Scala kernel, or IPython?

Comment: Its an ipykernel.

Comment: what happens when you do `%%sh (newline) ls`?

Comment: same as %ls ;

talking to people around me it turned out, I cannot run a spark job (e.g. spark-submit) inside a spark-job (e.g. juypter notebook)